# Где изменить выводимые сообщения валидации ORM при регистрации нового юзера в модуле AUTH

Tags: kohana

Доброго вам времени суток!!

при регистрации нового юзера, методом

```
$user=ORM::factory('User');
        try {
                        $user->create_user($_POST,array(
                        'username',
                        'password',
                        'email',                            
                    ));

            $role = ORM::factory('Role')->where('name', '=', 'login')->find();
            $user->add('roles', $role);

        }}
        catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {
            $errors = $e->errors('orm-validation', true);
        }
например юзер вводит уже существующий в базе email выдается сообщение 
orm_validation/user.email.unique
подскажите как изменить выводимое сообщение
```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте файл `/application/messages/orm_validation/user.php` с таким содержанием:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

return array(
    'email' => array(
        'unique'=>'Email уже зарегистрирован',
    ),
);
```